# Maintenance Program with a txt file

Tags: c#, ajax

I need to write an employee maintenance program (in C#) that can add, change and delete from a text file.  I have the HTML all put into an .aspx file but I have NO clue on how to set it up to read from a text file and populate the input fields with the employee to maintain.

If I could get some insight on how to read a text file and populate the input fields(form fields) that would be great.  Even a link that explains it since I haven't been able to find one.  The text file will have to have a record ID as the first field so I know which one to grab for editing(to display) or deleting.

Comment: So this is ASP.Net?  Webforms or MVC?  What .Net version?

Comment: The key, like all programming, is to break the problem down. Writing to a text file has nothing to do with web programming, look at File for this. You seem to have the web side, can you communicate from client to server?  Which individual part of this is causing you a problem?

Comment: There are alternatives such as [SQL Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions/2012-editions/express.aspx), and [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/different.html) which you can run locally on the Web server to host your application's data.

Comment: I am using MVS and it is .NET Framework 4.  As I said below the programmer who has assigned this to me said that AJAX was the way to go although I don't know that either.  I believe the big problem that I have is not writing to the text file, it is reading and populating the text boxes and drop downs with the data.  I saw an example of reading and populating ONE text box but that reads the whole line.  My file has multiple fields on a line.

Answer (score 2):

There's a [toolkit of functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx) to manipulate files in the system.io.file class. That's a reasonable start for the project.

You might also consider using a database instead of a text file. They're designed to handle storage and retrieval of data that changes a lot. A text file is doing it the hard way.

Comment: I can not use a database because the people using the program can not connect to it for security reasons.  This data will populate and update a database daily I believe...I am not sure how often.  I am thinking the other programmer is setting me up to fail because he knows I know nothing about C#.  He did ask me how I was doing and I told him I could not find any tutorials on doing this so I am not getting anywhere.  He said "AJAX" is the way to go and I don't know that either.

Comment: Ajax is a web technology. Is this supposed to be running on a web server or is it a client application?

Comment: it is going to be running on a web server......

Comment: Take a look at the file class. There are a lot of examples on the web showing how to append to text files.

Comment: that is appending, adding should not be a problem, I do not have to get anything out of the text file just add to it. It is the updating where I need to populate the form fields with the data from the text file that I don't know how to do.  I figure if I can get the updating part down I should be able to figure out the deleting part.